# purging Gallery in calling Activity for Honeycomb to avoid OOME?

Tags: android, bitmap, gallery, android-3.0-honeycomb, out-of-memory

I am building a book viewer for Android 3.0 Honeycomb. It has been working fine on the Samsung Galaxy Tab but gets a lot of OutOfMemoryErrors on the Motorola Xoom on 3.0.1. Both devices have 48MB VM heap space.

I have 2 activities:

`BookActivity` - has a `SlowGallery` which loads 1280x640 images and a small Gallery which loads 160x80 images.

The `SlowGallery` is a minor override to make it fling one gallery item at a time instead of scrolling quickly.

`BitmapActivity` - has a single `ImageView` which loads an 4488x2244 image and a small Gallery which loads 160x80 images. Reducing the size of the image is not an option because the user is intended to enlarge the image to 100%.

I put this in the Bitmap-loading method to reduce the bitmap to 16-bit:

```
BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
if (compressColor) o2.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
o2.inPurgeable = true;
o2.inInputShareable = true;
o2.inSampleSize = (int) scale;
b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o2);
```

When I double-tap the BookActivity's Gallery, it calls BitmapActivity, passing the respective image number to be opened. I can do this 1-3 times, entering the BitmapActivity, then clicking Back, before it hits an OutOfMemoryError.

On double-tapping the Gallery it calls PageAdapter.purge(), which appears to visually unload the gallery's images.

This is BookActivity.PageAdapter, which is the adapter for the SlowGallery:

```
private class PageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Page currentPage;
private boolean purge = false;
private WeakReference<Bitmap> weakReferenceBitmap;
public PageAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
public void unpurge() {
    purge = false;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}   
public void purge() {
    purge = true;
    holder = null;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}       
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (listPages==null || purge) return 0;
    return listPages.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_pages, null);
        holder = new ViewHolderIssues();
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewPage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolderIssues) convertView.getTag();
    }
    if (position < listPages.size()) {
        currentPage = listPages.get(position);
        File f = new File(Engine.PATH + currentPage.getImageMedium());
        if (!purge) {
            if (!f.exists()) {
                holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);
                Engine.triggerTrickle(currentPage.getImageMedium(), WeightedAsset.IMAGE_MEDIUM, getApplicationContext());                   
            } else {
                weakReferenceBitmap = new WeakReference<Bitmap>(Engine.loadImageFromBitmap(currentPage.getImageMedium(), screenWidth, 1, true));
                if (weakReferenceBitmap.get()!=null) {
                    holder.image.setImageBitmap(weakReferenceBitmap.get());
                } else {
                    holder.image.setImageDrawable(null);
                }
            }
        } else {
            weakReferenceBitmap.clear();
            holder.image.setImageDrawable(null);
            holder = null;
            System.gc();
        }
        f = null;
    }
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Looking at the HPROF file, under the Dominator Tree, it appears that the `BookActivity.SlowGallery` still exists even when I am in `BitmapActivity`. When in `BookActivity`, `SlowGallery` takes up 3.2-6.5MB (1.6MB per image) but in `BitmapActivity` it takes up 1.6MB (`SlowGallery.LinearLayout.ImageView.BitmapDrawable` = 1.6MB). How do I get rid of `SlowGallery`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, kinda complex chunk of code there. The weak references may help, but in general, if using an ImageView in an adapter, before you set the new bitmap you should fetch the old Bitmap and then call `Bitmap.recycle()`. You should also do that your BitmapActivity when it is `destroy`ed. That should do most of what you need.

Comment: (blanked out to use answer question box)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I've managed to refactor it to recycle the bitmap. However, the gallery was still sticking around because `BitmapActivity.onCreate` gets called before `BookActivity.onDestroy`. If I did call the purge() function I would manage to clear most of it except for the clicked/selected view (kept alive by the `Gallery` double-tap listener!)

I then wiped out the darned gallery and put my own `ImageView imageviewCurrentPage` (and a `ImageView imageviewFlipperPage`) and animated them in and out. The imageviewFlipperPage would be destroyed immediately when the animation was done, so I was guaranteed to only have 2 bitmaps loaded at maximum. The `Gallery` can take up to **FIVE** Views with the selected, clicked views etc.

I also added this to further isolate memory usage:

```
<activity android:name=".BitmapActivity" android:process=":BitmapActivity" ...>
```

However, it came with the complication that static classes are not shared across processes. Hence, if in BookActivity I did Engine.SESSION_ID=5 where SESSION_ID is static, I would not be able to read it in BitmapActivity's Engine.SESSION_ID.